# Como puedo detener un hilo cuando cierro un Form

Tags: c#, hilos, bucles

Tengo un hilo en bucle para checar la base de datos cada cierto tiempo, se inicia cuando el Form se carga, y quiero que el hilo se detenga cuando el Form se cierre, lo estuve probando con impresión de números pero no logro detener el hilo.

```
Thread Imprimir;

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Imprimir = new Thread(Loop);
    Imprimir.Start();
}

public void Loop()
{
    int X = 1;
    while(true)
    {
        if (!IsDisposed) //Mi intento de detener el hilo al cerrar el Form
            Console.WriteLine(X + " " + IsDisposed.ToString()); //Para ver si se detiene el Hilo
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Roto");
            break;
        }
        X++;
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Por cierto, el form no es el principal.

Comment: El código no es funcional. Me da error porque Checar es método y además es un Thread. No aportas código para Loop. Podrías aportar más código?

Comment: Perdón, copie mal el código, ahora si debería funcionarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La operación que pretendes realizar debieras de hacerla en el evento FormClosing:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(">> * Closing Form * <<");
    // Abortamos la ejecución del hilo
    Imprimir.Abort();
}
```

Esto hará que la acción pretendida (detener el hilo) se produzca antes del cierre del formulario.